# Are Tomcat jars meant to be added to the classpath?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, classpath

Since jars like servlet.jar are usually not downloaded on their own, but rather come part of tomcat/lib folder, should I just add an entry to them in the classpath? Is that the common practice?

I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to reference them yourself when you want to **compile** servlet classes. How to do that depends in turn on the tools used for compilation.

If you're using plain `javac`, then you *could* reference them in `%CLASSPATH%`. But even then, that's considered a poor practice since that would potentially pollute the default classpath of all other Java compilations/applications. Rather write a shell file which sets the classpath right on the current execution environment by utilizing the `-cp` attribute of `javac` command.

If you're using a bit decent IDE like Eclipse/Netbeans, then you should just integrate the server in the IDE and associate the project with it. The IDE will then take care about setting the buildpath right. You don't need to set any environment variables then.

You do not need to reference them when you want to **run** them. The servletcontainer will take care about it by itself.

#### See also:

- [How do I import Servlet API in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)

Comment: I think it is a good idea to integrate the server in the IDE.  Where do I do that in Eclipse?  Also, how can I run ant from Eclipse rather than command-line?

Comment: As to the first question, check the "see also" link. As to the second question, just drop Ant build xml in Eclipse project, rightclick it and choose *Run as* and then *Ant script*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a web application on Tomcat then the servlet-api.jar is in the classpath.

Comment: No, my question was more about compiling the application.